# How to place the euro symbol for currency at the end and not at the beginning of an output?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, currency

I am using JSF's 2.0 standard convertor tags to format some number output as currency. 
But i have a little problem, I dont know how to place the euro symbol at the end of the output.

This is what I did:

```
<h:outputText value="#{payment.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€"/>
</h:outputText>
```

The output I get is:

> €15.55

But the desired output is:

15,55€

Can someone give me advice on how to solve this little issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The format is dependent on the [locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) of the view. The locale can be set in 2 ways.

1. Generically by the `locale` attribute of the [`<f:view>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html) tag:

   ```html
   <f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">
   ```
2. Specifically by the `locale`attribute of the [`<f:convertNumber>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertNumber.html) tag:

   ```html
   <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="#{bean.locale}" />
   ```

It's unclear what locale you're targeting, but the use of `,` as fraction separator and the placement of `€` *after* the currency is typical for among others Germany (`de-DE`), France (`fr-FR`) and Portugal (`pt-PT`). So you need to set it as such:

```html
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="pt-PT" />
```

It can also be obtained from a [`java.util.Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) bean property.

Comment: I just did it it works fine. I think the 'f:view' is a more flexible approach in case the locale changes the format of the currency should also change. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{payment.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="###,###.###€"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pattern` property of `f:convertNumber` as follows.

```
<f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="###€"/>
```

Check the following pages for more details.

- http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSFPage7.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html